# Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld (Tried many solutions on here)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Below is the code for I am using and the error I receive. This is on Mac OS X 10.9.4 in Eclipse.

CODE:

```
    public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

ERROR:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
```

I have attempted to delete and reimport the project, delete the bin folder, and check my classPath. It seems as though those problems have not been the issue in this case. I cannot seem to understand why I receive the error above. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your class in some package? Check your run configuration and build path.

Comment: and what file is this saved in ? HelloWorld.java or something else

Comment: Did you compile your code?

Comment: @Satya The file is saved in HelloWorld.java

Comment: @fumu7 This is in eclipse, so yes, it should compile automatically.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what do you mean? what do I need to check within run configuration and build path?

Comment: The run configuration shows which class Eclipse is trying to run. The build path will show you what Eclipse is compiling. Check that both contain your class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have checked the run configuration and the build path and compared them to a friend's run configuration and build path. They seem to be the exact same. We both are using the exact same code, with the same filenames/class/etc.

Comment: Not much else I can recommend. Try creating a new class (put it in a package this time) with its own `main` method and run that.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line before your `main` class:

```
package HelloWorld;
```